# Why does plainToClass not throw for invalid input types

Tags: class-transformer

Example:

```js
class Test {
  @IsString()
  readonly table!: string;
}
// note, that we call it with a completely wrong type: string instead of JSON-object
const result = plainToClass(Test, 'not a class');
```

Then `result` is the input string `'not a class'`!

I'd expect `plainToClass` to:

- return an instance of type `Test` where all properties remain undefined, or
- throw an exception

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I also found not [option](http://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/src/ClassTransformOptions.ts#L21) to make this work as expected.

The workround for now is to explicitly typecheck and throw in my own code:

```js
if (!(result instanceof Test) throw ...;
```

using [class-transformer 0.2.3](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/releases/tag/v0.2.3)

Comment: Created an issue [class-transformer#325](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/325)